# Animate Text widget to Appbar

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to Animate a **Text** widget which is placed in the center of screen to the **Title of Appbar** ?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child:Text('Animate Me!')),
    );
  }
```

How shall I approach to animate it in Flutter?

Edit :
I was imagining a Text fly and hover from Center of the screen to title of Appbar.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can animate the Text widget within the AppBar of your app. Your approach to animating the Text widget should be pretty much like any other animation. You can apply almost all types of animations available in Flutter. Please the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  //String text = "";
  Future myFuture;
  //Animation<int> _charInt;
  Animation<Offset> position;

  final String title = 'Flutter Demo Project';

  Future myAnimation() async {
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      vsync: this,
    );
    setState(() {
      // _charInt = StepTween(begin: 0, end: title.length)
      //     .animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeIn));
      position = Tween<Offset>(
        begin: const Offset(0.0, 0.0),
        end: const Offset(0.0, -9.0),
      ).animate(CurvedAnimation(curve: Curves.bounceOut, parent: _controller));
    });
    await _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myFuture = myAnimation();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final AnimatedBuilder animatedBuilder = _charInt == null
    //     ? null
    //     : AnimatedBuilder(
    //         animation: _charInt,
    //         builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    //           final String text = title.substring(0, _charInt.value);
    //           return Text(text);
    //         },
    //       );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)), //animatedBuilder),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //animatedBuilder,
            SlideTransition(
              position: position,
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time to write this Example. Actually I was imagining a Text fly and hover from Center of the screen to title of Appbar.

Comment: Well if you like, you could give a like (up vote) for my effort, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the vote. Please check the code now, I've updated it to make Text in the center of the screen fly up to the AppBar.